# How to store unregistered users in database?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains users of my system. The `order` table has columns:

```
id | user_id | price
```

Where `user_id` is foreign key.

Problem is that if user not registered there is no `user_id`. It means order cannot be placed because violates the integrity.

Comment: How do you want to link the order to a person when you don't save anything about the person like name or shipment address?

Comment: It is enough to know only order details address of delivery, name recipient and etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the table structures you have related to users, orders and shipment/address information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `user_id` nullable and insert a `NULL`, if there's no user associated with an order.

Comment: i think this is a bad idea, as he must save the data at least for the taxes and hehas to link the order to the address

Answer (score 0):

add a column to your user table where you mark if he is registered or not.

With this you can make the whole registration process, if need be, else you keep the unregistered users, till taxes and law it requires and the delete the users whenit is proper.